# Should reading negative into unsigned fail via std::cin (gcc, clang disagree)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, cin, std

For example,

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  unsigned n{};
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cout << n << ' ' << (bool)std::cin << std::endl;
}
```

When input `-1`, [clang 6.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2YbMJjgp43pq0jDK) outputs `0 0` while [gcc 7.2.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XtnWK8sHLibQ6ZFy) outputs `4294967295 1`. I'm wondering who is correct. Or maybe both are correct for the standard does not specify this? By fail, I take to mean `(bool)std::cin` be evaluated false. clang 6.0.0 fails input `-0` too.

---

As of Clang 9.0.0 and GCC 9.2.0, both compilers, using either libstdc++ or libc++ in the case of Clang, agree on the result of the program above, independent of the C++ version (>= C++11) used, and print

```
4294967295 1
```

i.e. they set the value to `ULLONG_MAX` and do not set the failbit on the stream.

Comment: What does "fail" mean here? You can't get -1, that's for sure.

Comment: Have been trying to answer this ... it's a rabbit hole.  At a minimum could you add what C++ standard you are compiling against there are so many "up to", "after" etc changes that not knowing this is going to make it almost impossible to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson I would assume that 'fail' means that `failbit` of the input stream was set - and therefore the second output would be 0 rather than 1.

Comment: @RichardCritten Added C++17 tag.

Comment: Additional references: [libc++ bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36914) resulting in the changed behavior and [LWG issue](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1169) resulting in C++17 change. From neither of those it is clear to me whether failbit should be set.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think that both are wrong in C++17<sup>1</sup> and that the expected output should be:

```
4294967295 0
```

While the returned value is correct for the latest versions of both compilers, I think that the `ios_­base​::​failbit` should be set, but I also think there is a confusion about the notion of **field to be converted** in the standard which may account for the current behaviors.

The standard says — [[facet.num.get.virtuals#3.3]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/facet.num.get.virtuals#3.3):

> The sequence of chars accumulated in stage 2 (the field) is converted to a numeric value by the rules of one of the functions declared in the header `<cstdlib>`:
>
> - For a signed integer value, the function `strtoll`.
> - For an unsigned integer value, the function `strtoull`.
> - For a floating-point value, the function `strtold`.

So we fall back to [`std::strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul), which must return<sup>2</sup> `ULLONG_MAX`  and not set `errno` in this case (which is what both compilers do).

But in the same block (**emphasis** is mine):

> The numeric value to be stored can be one of:
>
> - zero, if the conversion function does not convert the entire field.
> - the most positive (or negative) representable value, if the **field to be converted** to a signed integer type represents a value too large positive (or negative) to be represented in `val`.
> - the most positive representable value, if the **field to be converted** to an unsigned integer type represents a value that cannot be represented in `val`.
> - the converted value, otherwise.
>
> The resultant numeric value is stored in `val`. If the conversion function does not convert the entire field, or if the field represents a value outside the range of representable values, `ios_­base​::​failbit` is assigned to `err`.

Notice that all these talks about the ***"field to be converted"*** and not the actual value returned by `std::strtoull`. The field here is actually the widened sequence of character `'-', '1'`.

Since the field represents a value (-1) that cannot be represented by an `unsigned`, the returned value should be `UINT_MAX` and the failbit should be set on `std::cin`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>`clang` was actually right prior to C++17 because the third bullet in the above quote was:</sub>

> <sub>- the most negative representable value or zero for an unsigned integer type, if the field represents a value too large negative to be represented in `val`. `ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> [`std::strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) returns `ULLONG_MAX` because (thanks @NathanOliver) —  C/7.22.1.4.5:</sub>

> <sub>If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of base is zero, the sequence of characters starting with the first digit is interpreted as an integer constant according to the rules of 6.4.4.1.
> [...]
> If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type).</sub>

Comment: I beleive what you are looking for is *the sequence of characters starting with the first digit is interpreted as an integer constant according to the rules of 6.4.4.1.* with *If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)* from 7.22.1.4.5 of the C standard.  I think with that it would make this answer "standard complete" :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I did add this but I am actually rewriting the answer because I found some other evidences in the standard - I am deleting it while I edit it. Thanks for the quote anyway!

Comment: @NathanOliver I have updated the answer, I would be happy to get your point of view on it.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got your second quote but it doesn't match what I have for C++17: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/facet.num.get.virtuals#3.3.  According to that it should be the most positive value.

Comment: Ah, looked at my C++11 draft and that is the language in there.  Looks like there was a change somewhere along the line.

Comment: @NathanOliver N4296 (C++14 latest draft if I am not wrong), I'll update with your quote since this question is tagged C++17. I don't think this change my conclusion.

Comment: Aha, I was still thinking it should store the max in `n` but iirc if failbit is set then the value passed to `cin` gets set to 0. +1

Comment: @NathanOliver It failbit is set, shouldn't the value not be touched instead of being set to `0`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that you are actually right and that `n` should equals `UINT_MAX` but the failbit should be set, so both compiler would be wrong?

Comment: @Lingxi and holt, at least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378911/why-does-cin-expecting-an-int-change-the-corresponding-int-variable-to-zero-in) says it should be set to 0.

Comment: @NathanOliver I did not find reference in [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/istream.formatted.arithmetic), and I just remembered why I never answered stream related questions in C++ ;)

Comment: No kidding.  Streams are a PITA.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, I think that cppreference (and the linked answer) are referencing the first bullet above *"zero, if the conversion function does not convert the entire field."* which happens if the input does not contain a valid number.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  If that is the case then both are wrong as the output should be 4294967295 0: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea3475f2633adcd9.  Too bad I can't +1 again

Comment: At the end you're saying that the fail bit should be set, but at the beginning you say it shouldn't...

Comment: @Holt Oh, never mind. I boolean notted what you said.

Comment: Note that the [strtoul example at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul#Example) converts -40 to unsigned without a problem, so why would -1 be an error?

Comment: @BoPersson This is mentioned in my answer - The behavior of `strtoull`  is expected, but the return value of `std::num_get::get` is not directly the converted value returned by `strtoull`, which is what I discuss in the end of my answer.

Comment: @BoPersson In particular, the quote *"the most positive representable value, if the field **to be converted** to an unsigned integer type represents a value that cannot be represented in val."* imply (from my point of view) a check on the actual sequence of characters, and not only on the return value of `strtoull`.

Comment: Another plausible reading is that the value represented by "the field to be converted" is the value determined from `strto*`'s rules, which would make GCC right.

Comment: @T.C. I agree this is not 100% unambiguous but why use "the field to be converted" instead of "the converted value" in this case? Furthermore, even in this case gcc would likely be wrong since the converted function is strtoull which would return ULLONG_MAX that is likely not representable by an unsigned int.

Comment: @Holt This came up in another question and I noticed that recent versions of GCC and Clang are in agreement on this, but disagree with your answer. Could you revisit it?

Comment: @uneven_mark Can you point me to this other question? I did not notice changes in the standard that could affect this, so I will currently stand on my ground on this (even after re-reading this for the 10th time) unless proven otherwise or unless there is some "official" reasoning from gcc and clang.

Comment: @Holt This problem wasn't really discussed, but in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476766/c-negative-verification-is-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) the code would have worked as OP intended if the failbit was set for negative inputs, although OP of that question seemed to have had misunderstood `unsigned` in general. I was surprised of the behavior when I tested it myself and searched for a related question, ending up here.

Comment: Since this seems like a very basic question to ask when doing IO, I thought it was worthwhile to ask for clarification. Maybe someone else will provide reasoning from the standard libraries point of view for the behavior, especially libc++'s, which seems to have changed since this question was posted originally.

Comment: @Holt [Here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36914#c3) is a comment in the bug report that caused the change in libc++'s behavior discussing whether the failbit should be set. I don't know whether this adds anything new to this thread.

Comment: @uneven_mark That's the current standard I think. If you read the standard for the C functions `strto*`, you'll notice how hard to understand they are (just check the quote [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_006.html)). From my point of view, both gcc and clang follows the specification of the C functions for the returned value now (see https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/f382e530159b42de9120ddecaf57d540471f5962 for clang). [...]

Comment: @uneven_mark [...] But as far as I understand, when checking if `err` needs to be set or not (in `num_get`, see, e.g., http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1169), there is  mention of *field to be converted*, which the **to be** leads me to think that extra checks need to performed by `num_get`, regardless of the `errno` state or the value returned by `strto*`.

Answer (score 2):

*The question is about differences between the library implementations [libc++](/questions/tagged/libc%2b%2b) and [libstdc++](/questions/tagged/libstdc%2b%2b) - and not so much about differences between the compilers([clang](/questions/tagged/clang), [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc)).*

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) clears these inconsistencies up pretty well:

> The result of converting a negative number string into an unsigned
>   integer was specified to produce **zero** until [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), although some
>   implementations followed the protocol of [`std::strtoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) which negates
>   in the target type, giving [`ULLONG_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) for "-1", and so produce the
>   largest value of the target type instead. As of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), strictly
>   following [`std::strtoull`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) is the correct behavior.

This summarises to:

- `ULLONG_MAX` (`4294967295`) is correct going forward, since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) (both compilers do it correct now)
- Previously it should have been `0` with a strict reading of the standard ([libc++](/questions/tagged/libc%2b%2b))
- Some implementations (notably [libstdc++](/questions/tagged/libstdc%2b%2b)) followed `std::strtoull` protocol instead (which now is considered the correct behavior)

---

The failbit set and why it was set, might be a more interesting question (at least from the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) perspective). In [libc++](/questions/tagged/libc%2b%2b) ([clang](/questions/tagged/clang)) version 7 it now does the same as [libstdc++](/questions/tagged/libstdc%2b%2b) - this seems to suggest that it was chosen to be same as going forward (even though this goes against the letter of standard, that it should be zero before [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) - but so far I've been unable to find changelog or documentation for this change.

The interesting block of text reads (assuming pre-c++17):

> If the conversion function results in a negative value too large to
>   fit in the type of v, the most negative representable value is stored
>   in v, **or zero for unsigned integer types**.

According to this, the value is specified to be `0`. Additionally, no where is it indicated that this should result in setting the failbit.

Comment: The top answer does say the same about the value set. However it additionally asserts that the failbit should be set in both cases, which is not what the current compilers do. The cppreference page is not explicitly mentioning whether it should be set. Is this supposed to mean that it should not be set in either case? Then the old Clang behavior would be wrong as well. I think this is what needs to be explained explicitly.

Comment: @uneven_mark i have updated my answer - it turns out clang did the same as gcc

Comment: This is a library issue, so you really instead of gcc vs clang we should be talking about libstdc++ vs libc++. Godbolt uses by default libstdc++ for both. You need to specify `-stdlib=libc++`, then you will observe OP's results. I think there needs to be a more detailed explanation for why the failbit shouldn't be set, given that this is a language-lawyer question and the highly upvoted answer is contradicting for both C++17 and before.

Comment: @uneven_mark im pretty sure this is a bug in libc++ (don't you think ?) - language-lawyer or not

Comment: I don't know whether it is. As you can see in the top answer there was discussion about what the standard actually means, as it says "*If the conversion function does not convert the entire field, or if the field represents a value outside the range of representable values, ios_­base​::​failbit is assigned to err.*". Standard libraries seem to agree now that this does not mean that the failbit should be set in this situation, but again the top answer argues differently. I don't know what the correct answer is myself.

Comment: I might go looking for the relevant libc++ patch later. It might contain at least libc++ developer's reason for the change (bug fix?)

Comment: @uneven_mark where do we find those ? I could tell they 'fixed the bug' from 6000 to 7000 by testing done by me

Comment: I would start by searching their bugzilla for a closed bug here: https://bugs.llvm.org/ If I found nothing I would try to figure out the relevant code in the library and git-bisect on the change. The commit message would then hopefully be helpful. This may be time consuming though.

Comment: I have linked the libc++ bug I found in the question comments.

Answer (score 0):

The intended semantics of your `std::cin >> n` command are described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) (as, apparently, `std::num_get::get()` is called for this operation). There have been some semantics changes in this function, specifically w.r.t. the choice of whether to place 0 or not, in C++11 and then again in C++17.

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe these differences may account for the different behavior you're seeing.