# C++ (negative verification is not working

Tags: c++, do-while, verification

Testing cin for non numeric, non zero,and  non negative values and entering loop.  Cannot see why the test for values <=0 portion is not working. it should output:

```
cout << "Invalid value input\n";
```

Thanks in advance for catching what is probably a silly error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int integer;

    cout<< "Enter a non negative number greater than 0: ";
    cin>> integer;

    do
    {
         while(!cin || integer <= 0)//validation condition
         {
             cout << "Invalid value input\n";
             cin.clear();
             cin.ignore(200, '\n');
             cout<< "Enter a non negative number greater than 0: ";
             cin>> integer;
         }
         cout<< "Enter a non negative number greater than 0: ";
         cin>> integer;
    } while(integer !=1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The would be a lot cleaner if you only had one set of the "enter a number", that is `do {` enter number, complain if bad `} while (` not 1 `);` .  But if you want to make it work as is please explain exactly HOW it is not working.  See [ask].

Comment: Are you entering negative numbers? Note that `unsigned int` cannot store negative values. Whether `cin` should fail on input of negative numbers for `unsigned` is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921271/should-reading-negative-into-unsigned-fail-via-stdcin-gcc-clang-disagree).

Comment: `integer` is `unsigned int`, meaning it can not have a negative value. So if you try to give it a negative value it will "wrap around" and get a positive value instead. If you want negative values you need to use `int integer;`

Comment: Thank you uneven_mark, That does the trick. I'll look into that thread for clarification on why it 'fails'.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because of `unsigned int integer;` .
Changing this to int integer to check for negative verification. 
Range of the value of an unsigned int is 0 to 4,294,967,295 (4 bytes)
So -1 in unsigned means 4,294,967,295 as -1 bit representation is 111~11 (32 Ones)
You may check [2's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for binary bit subtraction and how -1 became 2^32-1